# Exactly what does it mean that the quintic unsolvable

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to get my head around Galois theory and the unsolvability of the general quintic (or equations of higher degree). The fundamental theorem of algebra states that a polynomial equation of degree n has exactly n solutions. So the quintic has 5 solutions, this would mean $x^{5} + a_{4}x^{4} + a_{3}x^{3} + a_{2}x^{2} + a_{1}x + a_{0} = (x-R)(x^{4} + b_{3}x^{3} + b_{2}x^{2} + b_{1}x + b_{0})$ for some complex number $R$. And then a degree 4 polynomial equation is solvable. But the quintic is not solvable. It feels like I am missing something here.

Sometimes you read formulations like there is no radicals in the coefficients of the equation that solves the equation. But what about radicals with other numbers than the coefficients?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem

Comment: "Solvable" in this conetext means : "Solveable by radicals". You must determine the solutions only by taking roots and applying addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.

Comment: Usually, only polynomials with integer coefficients are considered. Then, the so-called galois-group over $\mathbb Q$ of this polynomial (usually irreducible) is determined. Then, the polynomial is solvable by radicals if and only if the galois-group is solvable.

Comment: The coefficients are called 'parameters', and it basically mean that they are the reason the roots are what they are.  Thus, it only makes sense to have solutions in terms of the coefficients.

Comment: You could think about it like this: *If* you could factor some $(x-R)$ out, then the quintic is solvable.  *But* you can't know what $R$ exactly is, since you can't solve for it in terms of radicals.  It is like the difference between $\pi r^2$ and $3.14r^2$

Comment: The Abel-Ruffini-theorem holds for every field with characteristic $0$. Upto degree $4$, a polynomial is always solvable ba radicals. For degree $5$ and higher, the galois-group might be non-solvable.

Comment: There does exist a formula that solves quintic polynomials, however, it uses things that aren't considered closed form solutions.  Mainly, Bring Radicals, if you wish to look it up.

Comment: Also it's important to mention that it's the *general* quintic is insoluble.

Comment: @snulty Correct. This follows from the Abel-Ruffini-theorem. If a general formula would exist, every polynomial would be solvable by radicals.

Comment: But in principle I could just have a lucky guess at a degree 4 polynomial and divide my original quintic with it and get the number $R$? Then I would have 4 radicals all solving my orignal equation. And one number not expressible as a radical? I guess this is what I do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

The Abell-Ruffini theorem does not say that an equation of degree $>4$ is unsolvable, but that , for such equations , there does not exists in general  a formula that gives the solutions in term of rational operations and radicals.

In your example, if one solution of the quintic is know, we can factorize it as you say, but if this solution is not known, we cannot find the factorization with some formula ( that uses only rational operations and radicals) that works for any quintic.

Comment: The Abel-Ruffini theorem is stronger than the claim that there is no general fomula for polynomials with degree $5$ or higher. This claim would leave the possibility that every equation would allow some special solving method.

Comment: In fact, a random equation of degree $5$ or higher is very likely to be non-solvable by radicals.

Comment: @Peter:  I modified a bit 'my answer. It's better now?

Comment: @Peter From Wikipedia: "In principle, it could be that the equations of the fifth degree could be split in several types and, for each one of these types, there could be some algebraic solution valid within that type. Or, as Ian Stewart wrote, “for all that Abel's methods could prove, every particular quintic equation might be soluble, with a special formula for each equation.” However, this is not so, but *this impossibility lies outside the scope of the Abel–Ruffini theorem* and is part of the Galois theory." (my italics) Perhaps you could comment on this.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Seems , I have misinterpreted the theorem. What should I comment ?